# To which Java data types can I map TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sqldatatypes

To which Java data types can (or should) my application map Oracle column types [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081) or [`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169)?  Can the Oracle [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) driver map these types to either [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) objects?  Does `Calendar` preserve the time zone value whereas `Date` does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JDBC 4.0 Specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) does not even mention time zones, so JDBC does not specify how a JDBC driver should handle SQL type `TIMEZONE WITH TIME ZONE` or how to interpret the time zone that may appear in a `TIMESTAMP` literal value.  So, the JDBC specification leaves time zone interpretation entirely up to the JDBC driver implementation!

Comment: Very true, that is why I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685017/crazy-ms-sql-server-jdbc-driver-at-datetime-field-or-time-zone-issue/